# Get PC to listen to server on VPN subnet

Tags: networking, vpn, port-forwarding

Have a pretty bizarre networking problem I'm trying to solve. It's hard to describe with words, so here's a crappy diagram I drew:
[image: Network diagram]
The PC can't directly access the VPN subnet (and therefore the laptop) but the laptop can access the main subnet. My first thought was to set up an SSH tunnel to the PC on that port, but SSH tunneling is only TCP, and the server is UDP. I also tried setting up a UDP tunnel on the VPN server to the laptop, and then having the Windows PC listen to the VPN server, but everything I tried would give me an error as the port was already in use by the server on 26760, so I'm not sure how I could possible forward that port elsewhere if you can't forward a port that's already in use. I feel like I'm missing something fairly obvious with that part but I'm not sure. Anyone have any ideas?